# Flink ParserError UNQUOTED_CHARS_AFTER_QUOTED_STRING

Tags: csv, apache-flink, file-read

I am trying to read a simple csv file with flink `readCsvFile` but ı get an error. I read hundred times the very same file with Apache Spark and had no problem. My env: Ubuntu, Intellij, Java8, Flink 1.9.2 and Scala 2.11.8. A part of my file is like this:

```
34,3,"Nike Women's Pro Core 3"" Compression Shorts",,28.0,http://images.acmesports.sports/Nike+Women%27s+Pro+Core+3%22+Compression+Shorts
39,3,Nike Women's Pro Victory Compression Bra,,21.99,http://images.acmesports.sports/Nike+Women%27s+Pro+Victory+Compression+Bra
47,3,Nike Women's Pro Hyperwarm Fitted Tights,,24.97,http://images.acmesports.sports/Nike+Women%27s+Pro+Hyperwarm+Fitted+Tights
57,4,"Nike Women's Pro Core 3"" Compression Shorts",,28.0,http://images.acmesports.sports/Nike+Women%27s+Pro+Core+3%22+Compression+Shorts
64,4,Nike Women's Pro Victory Compression Bra,,21.99,http://images.acmesports.sports/Nike+Women%27s+Pro+Victory+Compression+Bra
75,5,"Nike Women's Pro Core 3"" Compression Shorts",,28.0,http://images.acmesports.sports/Nike+Women%27s+Pro+Core+3%22+Compression+Shorts
80,5,Nike Women's Pro Victory Compression Bra,,21.99,http://images.acmesports.sports/Nike+Women%27s+Pro+Victory+Compression+Bra
```

My reading code:

```
// Define Products schema
  case class Products(productId: Int,
                       productCategoryId: Int,
                       productName: String,
                       productDescription: String,
                       productPrice: Double,
                       productImage: String)

  // Create dataset from file
  val productsDS = env.readCsvFile[Products]("/home/erkan/datasets/retail_db/products.csv",
    fieldDelimiter=",", ignoreFirstLine = true, quoteCharacter = '"')
```

I get the following error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.flink.api.common.io.ParseException: Line could not be parsed: '1037,47,"Nike Women's Pro Core 3"" Compression Shorts",,28.0,http://images.acmesports.sports/Nike+Women%27s+Pro+Core+3%22+Compression+Shorts'
ParserError UNQUOTED_CHARS_AFTER_QUOTED_STRING 
Expect field types: class java.lang.String, class java.lang.String, class java.lang.String, class java.lang.String, class java.lang.String, class java.lang.String
```

I put the quote character but nothing changed. Besides I can't believe that I am the only one with this error so far. I have barely found anything.

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove `""` from file with linux command  `sed -i 's+""++g' retail_db/products.csv`